# Webcam MotionDetection hidden Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, webcam, getusermedia, motion-detection

Im trying to make a pausescreen for a kiosk system. And want the ability to sens when someone is in front of the screen.
I used most of the code from [github -js-motion-detection](https://github.com/ReallyGood/js-motion-detection)

I dont want to display the webcam output on the screen,
When using Z-index motion is only detected in the areas that are visible to the user. And hide on the canvas elements gets overridden

How can i hide the videofeed and still use the motion detection ?

[Code here](http://goo.gl/2CkJD3)